# Pytest: How to test class variable that is set from environment variable?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using Pytest to test if a class variable was set correctly. This class variable is set using a environment variable. I want to make sure that it is set.

I tried using an autouse fixture on a conftest.py, setting the env var with monkeypatch, and it worked fine. However, the fixture executes before each test, and the class variable is set on import. If I import the class before the test, my class var comes out empty. If I import it in each test, it works, but it is not a good way to do it.

myclass.py

```py
class MyClass(object):
    my_class_var = os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')
```

conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('MY_ENV_VAR', 'TESTING')
```

test_class.py

```py
class TestEnvironment:
    def test_env_var(self):
        from module.myclass import MyClass
        assert MyClass.my_class_var == "TESTING"
        #this works

class TestOtherStuff:
#...
```

There will be more environment tests, as other tests on TestOtherStuff. I'm looking for a way to load the class AFTER setting the environment variable, without having to import the class on every test.

**EDIT - Solution in answers**

Comment: You could set the env vars in a session scoped fixture (or probably module scoped fixture if all test classes are in same file). That way, all env vars would be set before the test execution starts.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it after that, instead of editing the answer into your question. When a question is answered and accepted, you show the forum that your issue has been resolved, and future readers can easily see the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that looks elegant and is very useful if I need to mock other stuff. I used a fixture to set the envvar, import the package and return the actual class:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def my_class(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('MY_ENV_VAR', 'TESTING')
    import MyClass
    return MyClass
```

and the test:

```py
class TestEnvironment:
    def test_env_var(self, my_class):
        assert my_class.my_class_var == "TESTING"
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps whether try user scope control with

if **name** == ‘**main**’:
    main()

in this case ! We dont have import any class otherwise execute a class that you can.